# Best way to install popular apps on new installation of Windows?

Tags: windows, package-manager

When you install Windows on a new machine - assuming this is not done via cloning of hard disks / partitions - you want to install a bunch of applications, or pieces of software, on that machine: Things like a PDF reader, a second web browser, a SFTP client, Dot-Net and Java runtimes and so on. It doesn't quite matter exactly what the set of these apps - I'm asking about how to have them installed. Of course I'm looking for software solutions, but you could say that's in the general sense. So, options I've thought of, with a few examples:

- A Windows package manager:

  - Ninite
  - NuGet
- Slipstreaming software beforehand into the Windows installation image:

  - nLite
- A non-windows-specific configuration management tool:

  - Puppet

I don't actually have solid opinions, nor experience, with most of the above, so please feel free to recommend, or de-commend, any of them, or others.

Required features:

- Gratis
- Actively maintained

Desired features:

- Libre
- Does not require internet connection immediately upon installation

Comment: You already know Nuget and now you're asking me to recommend it to you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a hassle free way to install and update generic software packages on Windows?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/is-there-a-hassle-free-way-to-install-and-update-generic-software-packages-on-wi)

Comment: I can't say chocolatey or other tools meet the requirement: *Does not require internet connection immediately upon installation*, whereas `Nuget` would (I assume).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) which is a Windows package manager:

- Gratis & Paid versions
- CLI & GUI clients
- MSI, NSIS, InnoSetup, etc. plus runtime binaries and zip archives
- Install **and** configure
- Facility to bundle packages for offline install (Business/Paid Edition)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try [Scoop.sh](http://scoop.sh/)

Scoop is very scriptable, so you can run repeatable setups to get your environment just the way you like, e.g.:

```
scoop install sudo
sudo scoop install 7zip git openssh --global
scoop install curl grep sed less tail touch
scoop install python ruby go perl
```

Comment: How will those Linux command help the OP's Windows system?

Comment: Those are Windows Commands. The first command installs windows version of sudo. The commands are examples on how installations can be scripted. Find a list of of supports apps [here](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/tree/master/bucket)

Comment: I do apologize!! This looks interesting (+1). I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the official Microsoft way of creating install disks with all recent patches, which is known as "slipstreaming".

[Here](https://winbuzzer.com/2015/08/02/how-to-slipstream-windows-10-with-all-existing-updates-xcxwbt/) is a good article on how to slipstream Windows 10. To quote:

> Microsoft provides Windows 10 ISO files for clean installation of a
>   new system. Usually those ISOs lack the latest Windows 10 hotfixes /
>   patches / security updates. Luckily you can create your own up to date
>   Windows 10 ISO files when you slipstream Windows 10 with all existing
>   updates. What does it mean to slipstream Windows 10?
>
> The concept of Slipstreaming refers to integrating updates, patches or
>   service packs into the installation files of their original software.
>   Slipstreamed Windows ISOs allow a fresh installation of an up-to-date
>   Windows which is of great benefit for system administrators who often
>   manage hundreds of systems.
>
> But to slipstream a Windows 10 ISO is also beneficial for everybody
>   who installs Windows 10 more frequently for friends or family members.
>   To create a slipstreamed Windows 10 ISO you do not need special
>   knowledge and no commercial software. On fast systems the process can
>   be finished in just some minutes. Below you find the whole procedure
>   as a video and in a step-by-step tutorial.

[This Lifehacker page](https://lifehacker.com/5894838/customize-your-windows-installation-to-create-the-os-of-your-dreams) describes the process for Windows. The same should hold true for all modern Windows versions. I only mention the Windows 7 page for the quotes:

> Cut your install time in half by slipstreaming Service Pack 1 and
>   ***adding all your favorite apps to your install disc***, so you don't have
>   to sit there installing things each time you put Windows on a new
>   computer.

Comment: nLite simplifies/automates that actually.

Comment: Sounds good - do you have aURL?

Comment: http://www.nliteos.com/

Comment: Learning every day :-) It is along time since I slipstreamed; maybe I should get back into it, as I find myself reinstalling every few months. What I have been doing instead is using Virtual Machines, as I don't notice any slowing on my hardware. That makes it much easier to snapshot/backup & restore. Is that a possibility for you?